# Conditional formatting, can't bold by row gSheets

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting, countif

I'm trying to conditionally format by row in a google sheet. This is a register that links to other sheets in the same document, pulling data from each Purchase Request to summarize on the register.

I've successfully done row-based background-color changes based on text in one cell in the row, on this sheet. This works just fine:

`=countifs($D3,"*HS *")` with a green background color

However, when I try a similar formula to bold the row based on whether it's been sent or not, I can't get it to work. I don't see the difference. The 'F' column simply holds a marker to indicate that PR has been sent, or not. Sent items have an 'x' in that cell. I've tried using "" (empty string) for the unmarked items, and using a hypen. In every case, I get no hits on this formula:

```
=countifs($F3,"*-*")
```

I've duplicated the sheet if you want to have a look: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H1NnmnMqCC92Tsxl4P7I7z3ROUbwdKPLlnbVacuoGnw/edit?usp=sharing

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

conditional formatting in google sheets is priority based:

[image]

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much!